# Set position of equation for cases

Tags: horizontal-alignment, cases, justification

My equation has several cases and therefore I use the  `dcases` environment that is embedded in an `align` and `split` environment. However the first line is right-justified. How can I left-justify the first line?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
f=(1+1+1+1)\\
\begin{dcases}
(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) & z\ne0\\
(2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2)& z=0\\
\end{dcases}
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it something like this you want? I removed the split environment and used aligned nested in equation, specifying the alignment points:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
     \begin{aligned}
     &\enspace f=(1+1+1+1)\\
     & \begin{dcases}
    (1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) & z\ne0\\
    (2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2)& z=0\\
    \end{dcases}
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I need the split environment as I want only a single label. However I found the solution.

Comment: In this case, use the equation  environment, in which you can nest `aligned`. Please see if my updated answer is fine for you.

Answer (score 2):

We have to set markers in front of the first line and in front of \begin{dcases}.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
&f=(1+1+1+1)\\
&\begin{dcases}
(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) & z\ne0\\
(2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2)& z=0\\
\end{dcases}
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```